# jam or jamming, gerund or infinitive in this particular case?

Tags: grammar, gerund-vs-infinitive

> Sean wasn't as keen about maintaining his gun as a proper soldier should be, and that led to his rifle ***jam/jamming*** during the battle.

Is there only one right option here, or are both variants valid but have different meaning?

Comment: _Jam_ is not an infinitive here; it's a noun. _Rifle jam_ is a valid noun compound, referring to a specific instance of a specific rifle jamming. _No. 16 reports a rifle jam_. But it would have to refer to a prior context specification of the incident. The gerund, on the other hand, says nothing about context, just an action of the rifle (while being controlled by him). So, no difference in meaning, just in the context they can appear with.

Comment: @JohnLawler This is a full-blown answer.

Comment: "Jamming" is the only possible verb here. The non-finite clause _his rifle jamming during the battle_ is complement of the preposition "to".

Comment: @JohnLawler "a rifle jam" is idiomatic, but "his rifle jam" doesn't seem so. OTOH, grammar is your jam.